# How to convert an Integer into BigDecimal in Rails 4 Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integer

Ok, I'm generating some CSV from within an Order Model. So in my Model I need to convert a value stored as Integer (I've converted the value of the order into cents and stored as Integer) into money format: for instance, if I have `1198` in the database, I'd like to display it like `11.98`. How can I achieve this?

I've tried:

```
value = BigDecimal.new(value / 100).to_s
value = (value / 100).to_s
value = value.to_f / 100
```

But none of the above worked. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `value.to_f / 100` give you?

Comment: @MikeH If the original value was 1198, it gives me 11

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK `If the original value was 1198, it gives me 11` - it is impossible. `1198.to_f / 100` should give you `11.98` - it's the only option :) (because having either of the operands being a Float you'll always get Float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a Float:

```
(1198 / 100.to_f).round(2)
#=> 11.98
```

To get a BigDecimal:

```
value = 1198    
bd = BigDecimal((1198 / 100.to_f).to_s)
#=> 0.1198e2
bd.to_f
#=> 11.98
```

Comment: You have to convert the operators to BigDecimal prior do doing the operation, otherwise it's useless :(

Comment: @pj.martorell nonsense. Depends on the need. If one needs precise calculations she'd store data in decimals in the first place. Here, the author just asked how to convert something to BigDecimal, and he got answered.

Comment: @pj.martorell moreover, in this specific case, converting neither `1198` nor `100` to bigdecimal prior calculations makes zero sense - it won't change the resulting number.

Comment: I'm getting `BigDecimal.new( 100 ) #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class)`. Did this API change? I'm on Ruby 2.7.2.

Comment: Yes, it was deprecated. Use `BigDecimal(100)` now.